# Перевести имена файлов в ссылках в нижний регистр

Tags: html, linux

Есть локальная копия сайта (вернее, html-книга), которую писал очень "талантливый" человек.

Экспериментировал с именами файлов как на диске, так и в html-файлах. Ну а то, что имена иногда не совпадают, в этом ничего страшного нет, IE открывал все спокойно и красиво.

А теперь мне все это надо запустить под *lighttpd*, который регистр символов различать умеет.

Собственно вопрос: как этот бардак поправить?

То есть как привести все имена файлов и директорий в нижний регистр. Или в html-файлах хотя бы.

Ссылки имеют вид

```
 <td><img src="menu_im/MenuBot.gif" width="168">
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, типичный пример ссылки на файл (полностью весь тег `<a ...>`). лучше — прямо в вопросе, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 1):

исхожу из того, что:

- резервная копия есть
- текущим каталогом является «корень» «документа»
- ссылки представлены в виде: `href="ссылка"` и `src="ссылка"`
- внешних ссылок нет

---

в вопросе два подвопроса:

1. **переименование файлов и каталогов**. это можно осуществить комбинацией из программ `find` и `prename`:

   ```
   $ find -depth | prename 's,([^/]+)$,\L$1,'
   ```
2. **исправление содержимого файлов**. это можно осуществить комбинацией из программ `find`, `xargs` и `sed`:

   ```
   $ find -type f -iname \*.html | xargs sed -ri 's/ (src|href)="([^"]+)"/ \1="\L\2"/'
   ```